# Как заменить элемент в списке по индексу и сдвинуть наименьшее на начальную позицию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
chips = [400, 700, 900]
my_chips = 750

OUT: [700, 750, 900]

chips = [500, 900, 1200]
my_chips = 3000

OUT: [900, 1200, 3000]
```

Требуется проверить, если наша переменная `my_chips` больше одного из элементов в `chips`, заменить этот элемент по индексу, и сдвинуть наименьшее на начальную позицию.

Как так можно сделать?

Comment: `chips` отсортирован?

Comment: @dIm0n да отсортирован

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html):

> This module provides support for maintaining a list in sorted order
> without having to sort the list after each insertion. For long lists
> of items with expensive comparison operations, this can be an
> improvement over the more common approach. The module is called bisect
> because it uses a basic bisection algorithm to do its work. The source
> code may be most useful as a working example of the algorithm (the
> boundary conditions are already right!).

---

решение:

```
import bisect

def fun(lst, x):
    bisect.insort(lst, x)
    return lst[1:]
```

тесты:

```
In [57]: res = fun(chips, my_chips)

In [58]: res
Out[58]: [700, 750, 750, 900]

In [59]: res2 = fun([500, 900, 1200], 3000)

In [60]: res2
Out[60]: [900, 1200, 3000]
```

Comment: Да, но тут проблема в том, что удаление первого элемента делает линейным итоговый алгоритм энивей

Comment: [Проверил](https://repl.it/repls/ThinAbandonedSolaris), это решение всё равно быстрее

Comment: @dIm0n, я и не сомневался в способностях Python Core Team писать эффективный код ;)

Answer (score 3):

Вот так вот для непустых списков:

```
import itertools


def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def modify_list(l, val):
    i = 0

    for a, b in pairwise(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < val, l)):
        l[i], l[i + 1] = b, a
        i += 1

    if l[i] < val:
        l[i] = val


chips = [400, 700, 900]
my_chips = 750

modify_list(chips, my_chips)
print(chips)  # [700, 750, 900]

chips = [500, 900, 1200]
my_chips = 3000

modify_list(chips, my_chips)
print(chips)  # [900, 1200, 3000]

chips = [500]
my_chips = 3000

modify_list(chips, my_chips)
print(chips)  # [3000]

chips = [4000]
my_chips = 3000

modify_list(chips, my_chips)
print(chips)  # [4000]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(lst, x):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] < x:
            lst[i] = x
            break
    lst.sort()
    return lst
```